# Which API is similar to Twitter streaming API from which i can fetch the data from flume and do sentiment on that data?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, twitter-streaming-api

tell me the  names of such API's where I can practice my sentiment skills

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This is a opinionated question, which is not the focus of stackoverflow. You can post this question in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can try in tumblr blogs, or webserver analysis.